# Find and Replace all before a specific character in Visual Studio 2012 Find and Replace

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, replace

I have a large select list like:

```
.
.
.
<option value="A">A</option>
<option value="B">B</option>
<option value="C">C</option>
.
.
.
```

I want to use find and replace in Visual Studio 2012 to remove the tags, what's left should only be:

```
A
B
C
```

How can I use Find and Replace using Regular Expressions to achieve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

**Find:** <.*?>

**Replace:** *empty*

Comment: Just in case, not the "empty" word, just don't put anything (replace by an empty string).

Comment: Thanks this worked fine :) Now how can I bring all this in a single line like "...ABC..." ?

Comment: Change the find value for **\n** or **\r\n** (try both, it will depend on how the text file was saved)